# Is it possible to solve $x = y - \arctan\left(y\right)$ for $y$ analytically?

Tags: trigonometry

Is it possible to have an expression for $y$ in $x$ which satisfies the following equation? Or can I only solve for $y$ numerically?

$$x = y - \arctan\left(y\right)$$

I went down [Wikipedia’s list of trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities) but wasn’t able to find one that can help me out.

I also tried using [SageMath](https://www.sagemath.org/)’s CAS via `solve(x == y - arctan(y), y)` but only get `[y == x + arctan(y)]` as the output.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't express the solution using standard math functions, but I don't have a source for that.

Comment: I agree, this won't be solvable analytically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have already told you it is impossible to solve your equation for $y$ in terms of elementary functions. When $|x|\ll1$ and $|y|\ll1$ you can do with power series, as follows: From
$$x=y-\arctan y={1\over3}y^3-{1\over5}y^5+{1\over7}y^7-\ldots$$
you obtain
$$3x=y^3-{3\over5}y^5+{3\over7}y^7-\ldots \ =\left(y-{1\over5}y^3+{18\over175}y^5+\ldots\right)^3$$
and therefore
$$(3x)^{1/3}=y-{1\over5}y^3+{18\over175}y^5+\ldots\quad.$$
Taking the inverse series of the RHS we finally obtain
$$y=\left(t+{1\over5}t^3+{3\over175}t^5+\ldots\right)_{t:=(3x)^{1/3}}\quad .$$
Using Mathematica, or a similar algebra system, you can obtain as many coefficients as you want.